# IAP restore custom transactions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm new into iOS and I wonder is there any possibility to specify which completed transaction user wants to restore? Right now I'm using:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

And I can't find anything there to tell exact which transaction I want to restore.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are on right track. Add

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

And add delegate function paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished. In this function you can tack particular product id.

```
- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    NSMutableArray *purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
    {
        NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
        [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];

        if([productID isEqualToString:IN_APP_KEY_UNLOCK_SHIP_2])
        {
            //NSError *error = nil;
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ship2PurchaseRestored" object:nil];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it didn't help. Its not even going inside this code.

Comment: ok got it, add  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self]; Updated my answer..

Comment: Still the same. I had observer before, just after restoreCompletedTransactions. I've changed order anyway, but no difference.

Comment: check out your interface declaration:@interface IRInAppPurchase : NSObject<SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, UIAlertViewDelegate>

Comment: @interface IAPHelper : NSObject <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>

Comment: Right, I will try to do smth with that. Thanks again!